# Issue previewing data using console in Kafka Connect via spark streaming API

Tags: apache-spark

PLease I am trying to preview the data consumed from Kafka topic using Spark Structured Streaming APIs.
And it is stuck here for minutes, instead of it launching my spark CLI

Please Help
I already have my kafka topic with data being written to it after which I ran the command:

```
pyspark \
    --master yarn \
    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.3 \
    --conf spark.ui.port=0 \
    --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/user/${USER}/warehouse
```

But I keep getting the output:

```
Python 3.7.17 (default, Jun  6 2023, 20:10:10) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark-3.3.3-bin-hadoop3/jars/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark-3.3.3-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/dee/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/dee/.ivy2/jars
org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-b93cab13-37df-4a4c-9366-88c1ae221422;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.3 in central
        found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.3 in central
        found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.8.1 in central
        found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 in central
        found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.4 in central
        found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.32 in central
        found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.2 in central
        found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
        found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.2 in central
        found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 in central
        found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 in central
        found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 in central
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.3.3/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.3.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.3!spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12.jar (59ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.3.3/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.3.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.3!spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12.jar (20ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.8.1/kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.8.1!kafka-clients.jar (279ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0!jsr305.jar (20ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.11.1/commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1!commons-pool2.jar (24ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spark-project/spark/unused/1.0.0/unused-1.0.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0!unused.jar (17ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/3.3.2/hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.2!hadoop-client-runtime.jar (914ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/lz4/lz4-java/1.8.0/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0!lz4-java.jar (25ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.8.4/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.4!snappy-java.jar(bundle) (42ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.32!slf4j-api.jar (20ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client-api/3.3.2/hadoop-client-api-3.3.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.2!hadoop-client-api.jar (187ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3!commons-logging.jar (22ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 5105ms :: artifacts dl 1660ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 from central in [default]
        commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 from central in [default]
        org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.2 from central in [default]
        org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.2 from central in [default]
        org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.8.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.3 from central in [default]
        org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.3 from central in [default]
        org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 from central in [default]
        org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.32 from central in [default]
        org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from central in [default]
        org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.4 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   12  |   12  |   12  |   0   ||   12  |   12  |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-b93cab13-37df-4a4c-9366-88c1ae221422
        confs: [default]
        12 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (56631kB/113ms)
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.3.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.3.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/com.google.code.findbugs_jsr305-3.0.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.commons_commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.spark-project.spark_unused-1.0.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.2.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.lz4_lz4-java-1.8.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.xerial.snappy_snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.hadoop_hadoop-client-api-3.3.2.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
23/09/07 22:17:30 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/dee/.ivy2/jars/commons-logging_commons-logging-1.1.3.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had to check my system resource to see if the job actually executed, so when I ran the command

> jps

It turns out I had other SparkSubmit sessions/jobs that were still running that I thought I already closed, hence the memory was full and memory could not be allocated to my current spark session. So I had to kill/stop those spark sessions by running the command `kill -9 <job_id>` After-which I also verified by stopping the python kernels hosting those sessions, and my current spark job was able to load past that screen and grant me access to the pyspark interface.